# Why is the length column in SQL Server somewhat confusing?

Tags: sql-server

So I found out that the length column says "Length" is 4, and precision is 10 :

```
Col. name: SurveyNumber
type : int
computed: no
Length: 4
Precision: 10
```

And it has numbers like 19350 in it. Why is length called 4 and it has 5-digit numbers:?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

4 byte !

its not a 4 digits.

4 byte = 4*8 = 32 bits.

so it can hold 2^32-1  value number

( if you have a negative number so its half value -  symetric (-1) to the zero. - cause zero also counts.)

> min = -2,147,483,648 max=2,147,483,647

```
2^32 = 4294967296

divide by 2: = 2147483648

now step up 2^32-1 times

so you are here at : 2,147,483,647
```

Comment: ummm. 4*8 = 32, with a range of 0 -> ~4billion, or -2 billion -> +2 billion (approximately) depending on signedness.

Answer (score 3):

An int has a length of 4 because it requires 4 bytes (32 bits) to store a value.

4 bytes can store numbers from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 thus the 10 digit precision.

Answer (score 3):

All informations are available at MSDN.

[Precision, Scale, and Length (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx)

> **Precision** is the number of digits in a number. Scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point in a number. For example, the number 123.45 has a precision of 5 and a scale of 2.
>
> **Length** for a numeric data type is the number of bytes that are used to
>   store the number. Length for a character string or Unicode data type
>   is the number of characters. The length for binary, varbinary, and
>   image data types is the number of bytes. For example, **an int data type
>   can hold 10 digits, is stored in 4 bytes**

Answer (score 1):

Check the MySQL documentation, it's pretty clear over here : [Integer Types (Exact Value)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html)

A 4 byte storage (length 4) represents upto 2^32 values.